# PHP login does not immediately update webpage

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a webpage built on bootstrap 3. There is a link in the navbar to login. When a user clicks that link, a modal window appears and the contents of that modal window are from the file login.php. After they submit their username/password, the modal window closes

LOGIN.php:

```
<?php 
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['login_submit'])) {
      // I did not copy the processing to stop XSS/injection attacks

  if($username != "" || $password != "") {   
     $found_user = attempt_login($username, $password);

    if ($found_user) {
      $_SESSION["user_name"] = $found_user["username"];
      // should I have a http_redirect(?????????????) here?
      }
      else {
        $_SESSION["message"] = "Username or password do not match our records. Please <a href='../inc/register.php'>register</a> or try again."  ;  
      }
  } 
  else {} 
} ?>
    <form name="login" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"> 
<strong><center>Login </center></strong>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="input_username" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Username</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9"><input name="username" type="text" id="user" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
 </div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="input_username" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9"><input name="password" type="password" id="pass" class="form-control"  placeholder="Password">
    </div>
 </div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9"> 
    <input type="submit" name="login_submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-default" id="login_submit">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Here is the problem: once the modal window closes after the user clicks submit, the user is not logged in. They are only logged in after a manual reload of the browser window. How can I make it such that the user is immediately logged in and the session is started as soon as they click submit?

Comment: The HTML Center tag is deprecated. Just a heads up.

Comment: you can refresh the page auto with JS `window.location.reload()`

Comment: Or possibly `parent.window.location.reload()` if your modal is using an iframe

Comment: Thanks for the quick comments! I have a deeper question though: Must I reload the page in order for the login session to "take effect", or is there another way to do it? I don't mind doing the reload; I just want to learn about all the possible options for my own education.

Comment: @AndyGee I'm using a bootstrap modal window, which is not an iframe.  I suppose I can just use php to echo the javascript window - is that really the only solution to ensuring that a session data reloads, or is there a neater way to do it without reloading the whole page?